# Saving a Plotly figure as an PNG image in a zip file is very slow

Tags: python, plotly

I need to save a Plotly figure as an image in a zip file. I also need to store some texts that my program generates as a text file in the zip file. This is my attempt:

```
import io
import zipfile
import plotly.express as px
import kaleido

#write texts to stringIO
s = io.StringIO()
texts = ['foo','bar']
newline = '\n'
for text in texts:
    s.write(text)
    s.write(newline)

#create sample plotly figure
long_df = px.data.medals_long() 
fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")

zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()    
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, mode="w") as zf:
        fig_png = fig.to_image(format="png") # kaleido library
        buf = io.BytesIO(fig_png)
        zf.writestr('barplot.png', buf.getvalue()) #write plot as png file
        zf.writestr('text.txt', s.getvalue())   #write texts as text file
        
with open("a.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(zip_buffer.getbuffer())
```

It did create a zip file but it took perhaps 5 seconds to run. Am I implementing it incorrectly or is that just how it is? Please advise if there are better ways.

Comment: I tried to run your code. It took about 1 second by feel. I ran it on  `plotly:5.14.1`,`kaleido:0.1.0.post1`.

Comment: My kaleido version is 0.2.1, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: I am not on the latest version of this post. But I have not even tried to see if it is possible with the latest version. I get this information from this [information](https://community.plotly.com/t/static-image-export-hangs-using-kaleido/61519/3) from the community.

Comment: I had problems with Kaleido 0.2.1 in Windows 11 machine (my app was working fine in Windows 10). Reverting as @dataengineer22 suggests fixed that png conversion hanging problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Plotly is a heavy library in general, compared to Matplotlib. So, perhaps you could try switching libraries (as you are storing it as PNG anyway and not utilizing interactive features of Plotly graphs), which should improve times at least a bit.

Try `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()` instead of (Plotly + Kaliedo): https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Secondly, to improve resource management, you could use a `with` statement when writing to StringIO and BytesIO, which would automatically close the buffers after use.